# How to verify if a number has at most N decimal places?

Tags: javascript

How to verify if an input type number contains a maximum of 3 decimals, without using regex?

```
let x = 1.5555
let y = 1.55
x is false
y is true
```

Comment: Are you sure about your example? `x` contains more than 3 decimals and `y` contains only 2; if you want to validate numbers that contain *maximun* 3 decimals, `x` should be `false` and `y` should be `true`, not the other way round.

Comment: yes true, i correct it thank you

Comment: Any rational reason why not to use RegExp for this?

Comment: There are quite a few situations where it's best to reach for another tool instead of regex. For example: Regex isn't suited to parse HTML because HTML isn't a regular language. Regex probably won't be the tool to reach for when parsing source code.

Comment: Yes, though RegExp is not limited to regular languages only anymore. Anyway, your task is reliably executable with RegExp, there's no reason to avoid it in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a formula like:

```
(x * 10**N) % 1 === 0
```

Here `x` is your number that potentially contains decimals (eg: `1.555`) and `N` is the maximum amount of decimal places you want to allow for.

Eg, for numbers with 3 (`N = 3`) or fewer decimal places, you will get `x*1000`, which will evaluate to an integer. Eg:

```
1.55 -> 1550
1.555 -> 1555
```

For numbers with more than 3 decimal places, doing `x*1000` won't convert it to an int, it will only shift parts of the number over:

```
1.5555 -> 1555.5 // still a decimal
```

The `% 1` check then gets the remainder of the above number if it was to be divided by 1. If the remainder is 0, then the  number was converted to an integer, if it is more than 0, then `x*1000` failed to convert the number to an int, meaning that it has more than 3 decimals:

```js
const validate = (x, N) => (x * 10**N) % 1 === 0;

console.log(validate(1.5555, 3)); // false
console.log(validate(1.55, 3)); // true
console.log(validate(1.555, 3)); // true
console.log(validate(0.00000001, 3)); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to string using the `toString()` method, then split at the point `.` with the `.split()` method this will result in an array.
The first element in the array is a string containing the whole number part which is not interesting here for us.
The second element at indice 1 in the resulting array is the decimal part as string.

Now you can check the length property of this string if it is equal or less then three which means it has three or less decimal numbers then we return true in the validation function when not we return false.

```js
const x = 1.5555;
const y = 1.555;
const z = 1.55


function validate(num){
return num.toString().split(".")[1].length <= 3;
}

console.log(validate(x));
console.log(validate(y));
console.log(validate(z));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
let x = 1.5555;
let y = 1.55;
int length = x.Substring(number.IndexOf(".")).Length;
bool result = length > 3 ? true: false;
```